# Meaning of this passage from the Shulchan Arukh

Tags: shulchan-aruch

"With sex, how? He said to her before two witnesses: "Behold you are married to me with this sex," and he secludes himself with her before two witnesses, behold she is betrothed (even though she is bold.) Either he has sex with her in the normative fashion or he has sex with her in the non-normative fashion." ([Even HaEzer33,1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.33.1)).

What is meant by normative and non-normative sex?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/115398/history-of-extramarital-relations/115399#115399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant Hebrew reads:

> בין שבא עליה כדרכה בין שלא כדרכה

which is a euphemism, referring to either vaginal or anal intercourse.